# Button flyout menu items Collide With Buttons of lower layer and the button in the lower layer gets selected when trying to select the menu items

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

[image]

As shown in the figure the high menu item collides with Minimise button.How to solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Button flyout menu items Collide With Buttons of lower layer and the button in the lower layer gets selected when trying to select the menu items

[`Flyout`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Flyout) contains [`Placement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.flyoutbase.placement#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Primitives_FlyoutBase_Placement) property, Base on the your screenshot, you could set `Placement` as Bottom.

```
<Button Content="Empty cart">
    <Button.Flyout>
        <MenuFlyout Placement="Bottom">
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="By rating" Tag="rating"/>
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="By match"  Tag="match"/>
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="By distance"  Tag="distance"/>
        </MenuFlyout>
    </Button.Flyout>
</Button>
```